# How to display a UIImageView that fills the width of the screen, and sets height to keep aspect ratio?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have an image view I initialize like this:

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 200)];
[self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

I then fetch the image on the web and place it in the view. My problem is that I actually want to show the full image, and not crop it so it fits 200 px.

How I can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you inspect the image and calculate the width based on the image's dimensions:

```
UIImage *downloadedImage; // assuming this is not nil
CGFloat imageRatio = downloadedImage.size.height / downloadedImage.size.width;
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH * imageRatio);
```

There is a better way to get the screen width than using a macro by the way (`CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds)`), but that's not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the content mode `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` scales the image to fit the image view, keeping the aspect ratio of the image.

Your question title doesn't match your question body, so I'm going with the body:

> My problem is that I actually want to show the full image, and not
>   crop it so it fits 200 px.